# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol when put code into cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-members

I have a static member function defined in `.h` file, which is working fine.

When I was trying to move the implementation to `.cpp` file, the project build failed with LNK2019 error by another class that is calling this function.

Error message is:

```
8>------ Build started: Project: COrders, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
8>     Creating library D:\devel\Server\COrders\Debugx64\COrders.lib and object D:\devel\Server\COrders\Debugx64\COrders.exp
8>OrderProcessor.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl COAValidator::ValidatePercentage(class CSDO const &,class CExecInstHelper const &,class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > > const &)" (?ValidatePercentageXI@COAValidator@CPlus@@SA_NAEBVCSDO@AEBVCExecInstHelper@@AEBV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z) referenced in function "private: int __cdecl CPlus::COrderProcessor::DoCreate(int)" (?DoCreate@COrderProcessor@CPlus@@AEAAHH@Z)
8>D:\devel\Server\Server\COrders\Debugx64\COrdersd.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Here `COrderProcessor::DoCreate()` is trying to call `static bool COAValidator::ValidatePercentage()`, which provided via `.dll`

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show the code at least for this method please?

Comment: Did you create the `.dll` containing `COAValidator::ValidatePercentage()` yourself? Did you mark this method for export using `__declspec`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fully define this function in the `.h` file, it is compiled in to any client code which `#include`s that `.h` file, and no linking is required to locate the function definition.

However, if you move the function definition to the `.cpp` file, the client code can no longer see that definition at compile time, and relies on the linker to locate it. It's then imperative that the function is marked for `dllexport`, so that it is included in the `dll`'s function table.

This page describes the syntax for doing this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Our old code is still using `.def` to export symbols, which I had tried to add this function's signature in it but with no luck.

Comment: Update: just tried again by copying signature from the one in error message to `def` and it works.